# Opencart how to add php code to product/category description

Tags: opencart

Does anyone know how to, without purchasing an addon/extension, add php code to the product and category descriptions? If you try to add it automatically gets commented out when you save, e.g. `<!-- <?php echo "test" ?> -->`

**Workaround:** For anyone else.. I used borderless iframe to include an external .php file which contained the php code I needed ....

Comment: This isnt possible without modifying core code and using the eval() method in php which is *highly* frowned upon

Comment: dam .. thanks for letting me know, saves wasting my time hunting for solution. Looks like I'll just have to purchase the 'PHP Snippets' extension.

Comment: There is almost never a reason for purchasing an extension, unless You are not a developer or You need a large functionality that will cost You hundreds of hours implementing for Yourself (while could be purchased for few bucks)...